# Javascript: fadeIn() function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have two functions.

`setBindings()` that scrolls to the a particular div when a menu item in the nav is clicked.

`aboutSectionFadeIn()`, second function is a simple that uses fadeIn() to Fade in and Fade out a particular div.

**The issue is the setBindings() stops working on aboutSection div when I use the aboutSectionFadeIn() in my code**, it stops scrolling to the a div that is clicked. I don't understand why. Any idea?

Here is the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


setBindings();
aboutSectionFadeIn();
});

function setBindings() {
$("nav a").click(function(e) {
 // stops the a tags for working.. i.e. clicking to another page. Functions stops the functionality.
var sectionID = e.currentTarget.id + "Section";
// alert('button id ' + sectionID);

$("html,body").animate({
  scrollTop: $("#" + sectionID).offset().top
    }, 500)
 })

}

function aboutSectionFadeIn() {

$('#aboutSection').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, delay);
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 20) {        // If page is scrolled more than 20px
            $('#aboutSection').fadeIn(1000);
        } else {
            $('#aboutSection').fadeOut(200);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is `delay` defined?

Comment: First time using the function, I copied an example from online. So I don't know the usage. Perhaps it is the reason why code not working? Can you please explain

Comment: In your `#aboutSection` click handler you use a `delay` variable that isn't defined, which will certainly stop *that* function from working. Either define the variable, or replace it with `500` (or whatever delay you want).

Comment: Okay. I've changed it to 500. The problem is still there: setBindings() still doesn't scroll to the aboutSection. Just the aboutSection is having problem. But it works when I remove the aboutSectionFadeIn()